# Without modeling an entire starfield how would I go about making constellations for my world?

Tags: space, astronomy, prophecy

In real life constellations are stars, picked out amongst a myriad of stars. But in a fictional world, I don't have a field of stars to begin with and I'm not sure it would be worth creating one for that purpose. Also, how would I go about tying it into the world's universal horoscope?

Comment: What fidelity do you need here?  Do you just need to speak to the constellations by name, or do you need to have a drawing showing the night sky?

Comment: Why can't you randomly generate a star field? Here, [I googled random star field generator for you](http://www.peterkutz.com/samples/stars.html) Just click the generate button until you get one you like and draw your constellations and stuff from that.

Comment: Naming, but maybe a *few* drawings

Comment: @Aify that provides the ability (with a lot of experimentation) to make drawings of constellations, but *not* the means to name them. So that's half the battle! But naming them, using them for horoscopes are another matter entirely

Comment: @JesseCohoon Want me to google you up a random constellation name generator or are you going to do that yourself this time?

Comment: @aify I think i can do that myself. Tho lots of things like that ARE rpg based, but I assume it'll work for my purposes with some tweaking!

Comment: @JesseCohoon Generators are a worldbuilders best friend! By the way, if you need a world generator to go with that https://donjon.bin.sh/world/ is a  very good one.

Comment: No offense to OP or nothing but... this is a bit of laziness coming out of the question though I feel you may have good intentions.  A lot of this can be easily googled and how it all ties in to the horoscope is something only you can do as the creator.  This is why I provided it with a down vote.  Maybe if you came back with 12 constellations that related to your world and gave us some more information we might help with picking out human traits that may relate to them but as it stands now, this is basically a google and link question :/

Comment: @ggiaquin Which why I was going to delete it.. since it was pointed out. But someone answered too fast for me to delete it!

Comment: @Aify thank you for the generator site. I didn't have that in my collection of links

Comment: You could still delete it.  **You**’ll still see the post and its answers.

Comment: constellations don't really need a star field since the star positions does not really convey much of an image, just pick objects you want as your constellations.

Answer (score 3):

They are usually named after the people who discovered them or some form of mythlore such as Jupiter.  You can make your own maps easily with generators but the actual means to name them is rather simple and explained really well here by [Cornell University](http://curious.astro.cornell.edu/about-us/78-the-universe/stars-and-star-clusters/general-questions/340-how-did-the-stars-get-named-intermediate).  Let the [name generators](http://fantasynamegenerators.com/constellation-descriptions.php#.WJEVCfkrJhE) do the naming for you.  Find one you like and make up a story about the names.  That is up to you and your creativity.

Comment: Constellations, stars, and planets are all very different things that get named very differently.

Comment: I am well aware, however it still would be a quick google search and I at least gave him a starting point since it appeared he had none.

Answer (score 1):

Long and hard have I considered this question, and I have the answer.  Let us work backwards from the problems of the current system.  For one, the things represented by the constellations are a random assortment of stuff.  There is no theme.  More problematic, though, is how poorly the various things are depicted.  Orion's belt, I will grant you, is a reasonable belt.  The rest look like star kibble scattered by some frenzied cosmic pug.  Draco is a joke.

The author designing a constellation can work backwards, first deciding what the stars should represent and then carefully arranging the stars so these things are obvious and unmistakable.

The theme should be prurience, and all the constellations should be pornographic - frank depictions of acts and anatomy.  Yet the sky should be family friendly and we do not want to be crass: names for these constellations should be subtle and inoffensive: the Woodsman, the Eager One, the Twin Moons, the Little Girl in the Boat.

I think I do not need to elaborate on the Horoscope.